# Is there a web-based file viewer (not manager)?

Tags: file-management, webserver, intranet

I have a directory of files that I want to make 
accessible by web browser.

I'd like to see them exposed in a classic two-pane layout:

- a tree navigation on one side, letting you browse the 
  folder structure and nodes
- a content pane on the order, which shows the file
  if that file happens to be HTML, clicking links of course
  would update the content pane only (ala frames)

*"Extra credit:" preferred by not required*

- open source
- render markdown files directly
- render office docs
- render source code
- search files by filename
- search by content
- bookmarkable url
- add (upload)/rename/delete files
- edit files (text/html)
- edit files (rtf, xls, etc.)
- themable (so I can match look of our pages on intranet)
- no database; ideally this is backed by just the filesystem;
  don't want extra state floating around
- mobile support

*What I've looked at:*

- [lots of great web-based file managers](http://www.fromdev.com/2012/08/Best-Open-Source-Web-Based-File-Explorer-Applications.html), but their
  emphasis is on emulating desktop file managers, not 
  on creating a website that shows content

*A class of apps that might work:*

- web-based help systems are closer to what I'm 
  thinking of, but I can't find any that are backed by filesystem

Comment: any luck finding a solution to this?